# When is maven profile activation evaluated?

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

I've scanned the documentation for this, but have been unable to find an official answer.  When are the conditions for profile activation evaluated in a maven multi-module build?

From what I had understood, conditions were evaluated at the start of a build; during the pom processing.  However, I have seen cases where the activation of a profile is based on a file existing in the `${project.build.directory}`, which would imply that the activation evaluation can occur during the actual build process (which seems incredibly inconsistent).

Is there an official resource which indicates when/where profile activation is evaluated?

Answer (score 3):

The official resource and the only truth are the java sources. http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-model-builder/ explains how the effective model builder works, including profile activation.